# Why do degrees explain why plane lines, quadrics or cubics can't vanish on non-hyperelliptic curve of genus 3?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

On pages 205-206 of Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces, Miranda uses the canonical map of an algebraic curve to classify non-hyperelliptic curves of genus 3 as smooth plane quartics defined by the vanishing of a quartic polynomial. At some point, Miranda argues that no polynomial of degree less than four can vanish on such a curve for "degree reasons".

What degree reasons are these? I understand that we can't have degrees 1 and 2 since then the curve would have genus 0. I also understand that we can't have degree 3 since then the curve would have genus 1. What I don't understand is why we can rule out these cases for "degree reasons".

Comment: What level of technology are you working with here? The basic idea is that a polynomial $f$ vanishing on a smooth hypersurface $V(g)$ must have $f=gh$, but some of the details of "why" can be a little different depending on your setup.

Comment: Well we don't even know apriori that the curve is a hypersurface; in Miranda's book a an algebraic curve is defined to be a compact Riemann surface whose global meromorphic functions separates points and tangents. But the set up is to embed an algebraic curve X of genus 2 in projective space using the embedding given by a canonical divisor. Then given a fixed polynomial G of degree k, we define a map from homogenous polynomials of degree k to the the linear system of k times the canonical divisor and argue that when k=4, the kernel of this map is non-empty; there is a quartic that contains X.

Comment: The next step is to show that this polynomial is irreducible, which is where my question comes in. Maybe my question isn't even interesting, since I'm convinced that Miranda's claim is true, just for different reasons than I can think of. But when Miranda is speaking of degrees in this case, probably he means the degree of any hyperplane divisor of the curve.  The value of the hyperplane divisor of $f$ at $p \in X$ is $ord_p \; f/g$, where $g$ is a hyperplane not equal to $0$ at $p$.